# Ansible template append string

Tags: linux, ansible

The following template in Ansible

```yaml
ips: "{{ ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3'] | join(':6641,') }}:6641"
```

gives

```yaml
ips: 1.1.1.1:6641,2.2.2.2:6641,3.3.3.3:6641
```

I am trying to append `tcp:` in front of each item but not able to succeed. How do I append string here so it will look like

```yaml
ips: tcp:1.1.1.1:6641,tcp:2.2.2.2:6641,tcp:3.3.3.3:6641
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
ips: "tcp:{{ ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3'] | join(':6641,tcp:') }}:6641"
```

---

The next option is the modification of the items by the filter *regex_replace* in the first step and joining them later

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ips: "{{ _l|map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|join(',') }}"
      vars:
        _l: [1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3]
        _regex: '^(.*)$'
        _replace: 'tcp:\1:6641'
```

Comment: Bingo!!! this is awesome!! i didn't realized i can use `join(':6641,tcp:')`